# Bazel post build file copy

Tags: post-build-event, bazel, file-copying

I have a project where I am building multiple libraries and an executable using Bazel. I need to build a shared library and then copy it to another folder before I build the executable.

I can build the library, but I cannot figure out how to copy it post build. Best guess so far is a `genrule` and `cp`, but I am not sure how to implement it and ensure it runs after the library has built.

Is there a way to do this?

As to the why I need to do this:
I am building a Unity project that requires native code plugins to be built and placed in particular locations in the Unity project folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the rule in a Macro like so:

```
def myshared_library(name, **kwargs):
    unity_rule(
        name = "%s.lib" % name,
        **kwargs
    )

    native.genrule(
        name = name,
        srcs = ["%s.lib" % name],
        outs = ["dummy.output"],
        cmd = "cp $(location {}.lib) $(location deployloc)".format(name),
    )
```

Then replace `unity_rule` with `myshared_library`. Bonus points if you choose better names.

Not the most elegant way but should work